# how to remove dom reference and event delegation to dom elements/fields from object properties

Tags: javascript, closures

if I have an object with properties referencing DOM element, and delegates events on widgets/ fields in dom, will removing main wrapper dom element with jquery mainobj.properties.elem.$html_main.empty().remove() removes the events handler from other object properties($form,$table,$tab), and also do I need to manually assign each one(properties references) to null for GC. If I assign null to main parent object, will all children of it be automatically be eligible for GC. Like If I assign mainObj = null, will all child object, properties, properties.elem, properties.elem.$form.... etc be null and be collectible by GC.  Will there be lingering DOM links from child objecta after nullifying the mainObj.

my obj:

```js
mainobj {
    properties:{
        elem:{
            $form:'referencetoDOMForm',
            $table: 'referncetoTableElement'
            $tab: 'referencetoDivElement',
            ...
             },
        $html_main:'referencetomainDOM',
        otherprops:{ ...},
        ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the higher level object is no longer reachable because you nulled out the variable reference to it and no other code has any references to any of the child objects, then all will be eligible for garbage collection as unreachable by any code even though they contain DOM references.

FYI, in general, I avoid storing DOM references at all, but rather just retrieve them with a DOM query whenever they are needed at the start of some function.  This avoids any chance of leaking a DOM node because you forgot to null its reference somewhere.